# Combining point and polygons layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, geometry-generator, combine

I'm currently trying to compare species sample points vs their actual geographic range.

I have:

- a points layer with species names and each species has multiple corresponding points/records
- a polygon layer with the same species names showing the area each occupies

To avoid too many clicks from switching and toggling between vectors, I'd like to combine these layers so that when I select the species name, it shows both the points and polygon in one layer (e.g. third attached image).

Any suggestions?
[image]

[image: combined example]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could create "point polygons" by buffering the points layer, then merge these with your "regular" polygons into one layer.  Symboblize point polys & regular polys differently, such as by color on a category value.  You may need to control rendering to keep the point polys showing above the larger perhaps by transparency or by controlling rendering order in the symbology based on area.  Other methods to that are here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199430/change-display-of-a-shapefile-to-draw-the-smaller-polygons-in-front-of-the-bigge

Answer (score 9):

You can use pyqgis to 'link' the check state of category legend nodes for categorised layers by catching the `styleChanged` signal.

Copy the script below and paste it into an editor in the QGIS Python console. With this approach there are two layer name variables which need to match the names of your point and polygon layers. I used your layer names based on your comments below; just double check that they match. Click the Run button to connect the `styleChanged` signal of both your point and polygon layers to a slot function which will sync the visibility check state of the category child nodes.

```py
from functools import partial

# The two lines below are the only ones you may need to edit    
lyr1_name = 'Occurrences'# This needs to match your points layer name
lyr2_name = 'IUCNRange'# This needs to match your polygon layer name

project = QgsProject.instance()
lyr1 = project.mapLayersByName(lyr1_name)[0]
lyr2 = project.mapLayersByName(lyr2_name)[0]

tree_model = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()

def on_change(v_layer):
    ltl = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(v_layer.id())
    lln = tree_model.layerLegendNodes(ltl)
    states = dict()
    for node in lln:
        sp_name = node.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        check_state = node.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        states[sp_name] = check_state
    vector_layers = [l for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if l.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer]
    for layer in vector_layers:
        if layer.renderer().type() == 'categorizedSymbol':
            if not layer.id() == v_layer.id():
                ltl2 = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())
                lln2 = tree_model.layerLegendNodes(ltl2)
                for n in lln2:
                    n_name = n.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
                    if n_name in states:
                        if n.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) != states[n_name]:
                            n.setData(states[n_name], Qt.CheckStateRole)
                    
conn1 = lyr1.styleChanged.connect(partial(on_change, lyr1))
conn2 = lyr2.styleChanged.connect(partial(on_change, lyr2))
```

See the short screencast below for expected results:

[image]

To disconnect the signal/slot connections, run the two lines below (you can simply run them in a different editor (see end of screencast above).

```py
QObject.disconnect(conn1)
QObject.disconnect(conn2)
```

For reference I found a couple of similar questions/answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261090/checking-unchecking-rule-visibility-of-layers-at-once-in-qgis) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324254/catching-signal-when-rule-toggles-active-inactive-using-pyqgis?rq=1). My answer incorporates some of the code presented therein.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I've copied and pasted your exact script into my Python Console - apart from adding "from qgis.utils import iface" in Line 1. However, I'm getting an error "Seems there is no valid script in the file." Any idea what's causing this?  Do I need to set the "l" and "a" variables to match my layer names? I'm relatively new to Q and have yet to process using Python. My poly layer is 'IUCNRange' and my points is "Occurrences" and my project name is "OC".

Comment: I also get the following error - "AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeModel' object has no attribute 'mapToSource' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 11, in on_change
AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeModel' object has no attribute 'mapToSource'"

Comment: I'm using "3.16.3-Hannover".

Comment: thanks! I'm still getting error "NameError: name 'QgsProject' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 8, in was_changed
NameError: name 'QgsProject' is not defined"

Comment: @Fben980, I have updated my answer with a different approach which will work with the category nodes of your vector layers categorized by species. Hopefully you will have better luck with this approach!

Comment: working to perfection! Thank you so much! One last item: when I try to disconnect, I get the error "File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: disconnect(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'" Any thoughts on a fix? Thanks again!

Comment: @Fben980, I'm not currently in front of a computer. All I can say is that I tested extensively and it worked fine for me. Did you follow exactly what I did in the screencast? Open a new editor in the Python console with the green plus button, paste in exactly the 2 lines in my answer `QObect.disconnect(conn1)` etc. then click run. Note: if all else fails, simply restarting QGIS will disconnect the slots from the signals.

Comment: @Fben980, your screen shot shows that you are running this in the processing script editor but this not a processing script! Run it in the Python console code editor instead.

Answer (score 8):

A layer can only contain one type of geometry: either points or polygons (or lines), but not both.

However, using Geometry generators, you can create symbolization (visualization, not actual geometries) of another geometry type.

[image]

Let's say you have a polygon layer named `poly` with an attribute `polygon_species` and a point layer `point` with an attribute `point_species`.

On the polygon layer, add a new symbol layer of type `Geometry generator / Geometry type: point` and insert this expression. When you then (manually) select a polygon, all the points containing the same attribute value are created as additional symbols on the polygon layer (see screenshot):

```
with_variable (
    'selected',
    attribute('polygon_species'),
    if (
        is_selected( ),
        aggregate( 
            'points',
            'collect',
            $geometry,
            filter:=point_species=@selected
        ),
        ''
    )
)
```

*Polygon layer: blue, initial point layer: light blue dots; selected polygon (B) highlighted in yellow, points with the same attribute (B) highlighted in big red dots (style can be changed manually as you like. If you toggle visibility of the point layer, only the red B_points will be visible (as long as polygon B is selected):*
[image]

Comment: *"One layer can only contain one type of geometry: either points or polygons (or lines), but not both."* it is True when using the "Merge vector layers". What about the Geometry Collection then?

Comment: Which Geometry Collection do you mean / how to imply? If you create a layer, you don't have any option to but to stick to one type of geometry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTjKE.png

Comment: Bad me ... indeed QGIS is not ready for [Geometry Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Geometric_objects)

Comment: If you mean the "Collect geometries" algorithm, this accepts only one layer as input and does just collect single to multipart geometries (based on attribute values to group let's say all islands belonging to the same country together to a multipart geometry). The help says: "This algorithm takes a vector layer and collects its geometries into new multipart geometries. (...) All output geometries will be converted to multi geometries, even those with just a single part."

Comment: Geometry collection: maybe a feature request?