# Toggle on/off visibility of multiple features from different layers at once

Tags: qgis

I'm fairly new to QGIS (3.20), and there are things I think should be possible, but I can't seem to get them to work.

I have two layers with the same attributes, one of polygons (for regions) and one of points (for observations). One region can have multiple observations. The polygon layer is classified by the attribute "Project Nº" but the points layer is not necessarily classified by that same attribute.
[image: Picture 1]

Is there a way to control the visibility of features in the point layer that have the same attribute "Project Nº" when toggling the category in the polygon layer? Specifically, when I turn off the category '10077252,' I want both the polygon and all points with that same number to be hidden, while the rest of the points remain visible.

I think that maybe one way would be to introduce a new attribute called 'Visible' in my polygon layer. This attribute should be a virtual field with only two values, 'On' or 'Off,' and it will change its value depending on whether the category is visible or not.

Is this possible? I want this attribute to check the status of the category and change its value accordingly. I think that the field calculator can't read that directly, but maybe there is a function I can create to use in the expression builder?

The result would be that if the category "10077252" is toggled on (as shown in the first picture), the attribute "Visible" should have the value 'On', but when I toggle that category off, the value of the attribute should be 'Off'.

The idea behind this is so I can make the symbols of all other layers to check this attribute to display them or not.
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415393/combining-point-and-polygons-layers-using-qgis/415411#415411) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The second answer is very similar to what I want. The only problem is that I would like to do this with multiple layers, and the rest of them are not classified by their 'Project Nº,' even though they still have that attribute. Maybe my approach is wrong because it is way too complicated even if it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to add a 'Visible' attribute to any layers. The simplest way to solve this for the non-categorized point layers is to filter them to only the checked polygon categories by setting a subset string.

The code below is adapted from my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415393/combining-point-and-polygons-layers-using-qgis/415411#415411) and expanded to include any other point layers in the project which contain a field called 'Project Nº'.

You need to open a new editor in the Python Console (not a processing script editor!), paste in the below script and click run.

```py
poly_lyr_name = 'Proyectos'

field_name = 'Project Nº'

project = QgsProject.instance()

poly_lyr = project.mapLayersByName(poly_lyr_name)[0]

tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()

tree_model = tree_view.layerTreeModel()

def on_change():
    ltl = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(poly_lyr.id())
    lln = tree_model.layerLegendNodes(ltl)
    states = dict()
    for node in lln:
        cat_data = node.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        check_state = node.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        states[cat_data] = check_state
    point_lyrs = [lyr for lyr in project.mapLayers().values() if lyr.geometryType() == Qgis.GeometryType.Point]
    for pnt_lyr in point_lyrs:
        if pnt_lyr.renderer().type() == 'categorizedSymbol':
            ltl2 = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(pnt_lyr.id())
            lln2 = tree_model.layerLegendNodes(ltl2)
            for n in lln2:
                n_name = n.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
                if n_name in states:
                    if n.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) != states[n_name]:
                        n.setData(states[n_name], Qt.CheckStateRole)
        elif pnt_lyr.renderer().type() == 'singleSymbol':
            if 'Project Nº' in [fld.name() for fld in lyr.fields()]:
                unchecked_project_numbers = [int(k) for k, v in states.items() if v == Qt.Unchecked]
                if unchecked_project_numbers:
                    if len(unchecked_project_numbers) == 1:
                        pnt_lyr.setSubsetString(f'"Project Nº" != {unchecked_project_numbers[0]}')
                    else:
                        pnt_lyr.setSubsetString(f'"Project Nº" Not IN {tuple(unchecked_project_numbers)}')
                else:
                    pnt_lyr.setSubsetString('')
                tree_view.refreshLayerSymbology(pnt_lyr.id())
        
poly_lyr.styleChanged.connect(on_change)
```

When you have finished your work session, paste the following line into another blank editor and run it to disconnect the slot function from the `styleChanged` signal.

```py
poly_lyr.styleChanged.disconnect(on_change)
```

See screencast below for demo.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, that works great! Now, I'm going to try to add all the other layers and make it so that every time I open the project, this Python script automatically starts.